# how to group the values in a data frame by year into a table

Tags: r

i'm very new to r programming, i have data frame as follows

```
name   year    number
a      2017    10
a      2018    15
a      2019    64
b      2017    78
b      2018    57
b      2019    24
c      2017    56
c      2018    25
c      2019    54
```

and i want the output to be in a table like:

```
     2017   2018   2019
a     10     15     64 
b     78     57     24
c     56     25     54
```

this is just a sample, the data is actually very long( with abt 1500 rows) and not a matrix

i have no idea where to start, n i'm self learning r

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a very common question with lots of available answers. The procedure is called reshaping, or pivoting, from "long" to "wide" format. Many users would use `pivot_wider()` from the `tidyr` package to do this. So there are some search terms to help you.